Load balancing on VPS: uvicorn workers vs. docker compose deploy replicas
I have a fastapi service running in docker compose with traefik on an 8 core VPS.
In fastapi, i can parallelize the execution of the application by taking advantage of the multiple CPUs by running multiple workers. In this case, since my VPS has 8 vCPUs, I could for example run uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --workers 17.
Now in docker compose, there is the option to define in the docker compose file a certain number of replicas like so:
# docker-compose.yml
deploy:
  mode: replicated
  replicas: 3

Regarding the number of workers, i read that the best practice is 2* number of cpu cores + 1, so 17 workers in my case.
Question:
In the given example, an 8 core VPS machine, what would be the best mix of docker instance replicas and uvicorn workers?
When does it make sense to use replicas and how to mix the number of replicas properly with the number of uvicorn workers? If I would use 2 replicas, would that be 8 uvicorn workers then per replica? And if so, which approach is preferred and why?
Thanks for your help!
